# What is meant by this notation $G/ \sim_L$ and $G/ \sim_R$?

Tags: group-theory, notation

$L$ and $R$ regard left and right, and $\sim_L$ left equivalence and $\sim_R$ right equivalence, but what is meant by $G/\sim_ L$ and $G/\sim_ R$?

$G$ is some group and the equivalences are defined as below:

if $a \sim_L b$ so $ab^{-1} \in H$ for $H$ as subgroup from $G$

if $a \sim_R b$ so $a^{-1}b \in H$ for $H$ as subgroup from $G$

My professor told that those are the quotient sets regarding $a \sim_L$ and $a \sim_R$. Is this the elements of $G$ which $a \sim_L$ and $a \sim_R$ hold?

Comment: If $X$ is a set, and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, then for each $x \in X$ we can define **the equivalence class of** $x$ to be the set $[x]_\sim := \{y \in X : x \sim y\}$. With this, **the quotient of $X$ by $\sim$** is the set $X/{\sim} := \{[x]_\sim : x \in X\}$. This is elementary set-theory.

Comment: By the way, your definiiton of "left equivalence" is that $a$ is left equivalent to $b$ if and only if the *right cosets* of $a$ and $b$ (relative to $H$) are the same; and $a$ is right equivalent to $b$ if and only if the *left cosets* of $a$ and $b$ (relative to $H$) are equal. That seems a bit perverse to me...

Comment: Learn the equivalence of equivalence relations and partitions: https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MATH_220_Discrete_Math/6%3A_Relations/6.3%3A_Equivalence_Relations_and_Partitions

Comment: so $X/\sim$ is the set of the elements of $X$ that have at least another one equivalent element in $X$? $|[x]_\sim| \leq  |X/\sim|$?